# How to add ul element's style with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, styles

I want to style an ul element created with js

```
<ul class="form">
...
<ul>
```

Comment: Use CSS, not JS, for this. What is your specific issue?

Comment: everything is created and called with js so I have to write it inside the js file

Comment: The CSS can be included in the page before you add the content. Or if you're using an SPA, you could dynamically add/remove the CSS file reference - although this would be a very odd thing to be doing. There should be a single CSS file in the production environment which is bundled & minified.

Comment: I understand. I will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("ul.form").css({
  display: "none",
  color: "red", 
  width, height & other style elements 
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you should be able to use one of the foolowing to get the result you need.

```
$("ul.form").css("background-color", "#000000");
$("ul.form").css({backgroundColor: "#000000"});
$("ul.form").attr("style", "background-color: #000000;");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).